# Difference between TopicAdminClient and Publisher when publishing message

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I was going through Google Java Docs and figured out both class can do the same stuff when we want to publish message to PubSub(we can configure retry setting, batch settings, endpoint etc).

I would like to know when to use TopicAdminClient over Publisher and vice-versa, **do we have any performance benefits if we use any particular class**?

To be more specific, other than the comment below do we have any significant difference between the two class when we want to publish message?

> A Cloud Pub/Sub publisher, that is associated with a specific topic at
> creation

Answer (score 0):

Something magic with open source, that you can read the code and make your own opinion.

If you compare the [Publisher](https://github.com/googleapis/java-pubsub/blob/main/google-cloud-pubsub/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/pubsub/v1/Publisher.java) and the [TopicAdminClient](https://github.com/googleapis/java-pubsub/blob/main/google-cloud-pubsub/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/pubsub/v1/TopicAdminClient.java) class, you will immediately see the difference.

Publisher is specialized to publish message. Ok, raw message with default parameters, but you can also finely tune the flow control to have a better optimization of the communication with PubSub.

TopicAdminClient is specialized to handle the topic: create, update, delete. And also to publish roughly a message. No flow control here: get the message and publish it.

---

Now for your question, the perfect answer is, as always, "it depends!".

- If you use only publish method to publish a message with default parameters, there is no difference between both.
- However, if you start to play with the flow control and change the default parameters, you can have different performances between the 2 classes (better or... worse!!)

Comment: In TopicAdminClient we can set FlowController settings too, am I missing something here?

Comment: If so, I miss that part!

Comment: It's not true that publishing with default parameters makes `Publisher` and `TopicAdminClient`'s publish the same. The `Publisher` class by default does batching and asynchronously sends messages. The publish method in `TopicAdminClient` just proxies each publish call directly to the server. I'm not aware of the existence of a `FlowController` in the `TopicAdminClient`.

Comment: Hi @KamalAboul-Hosn - `TopicAdminClient` takes `TopicAdminSettings` as a parameter in `create` method as shown [here](https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/google-cloud-pubsub/latest/com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.TopicAdminClient#com_google_cloud_pubsub_v1_TopicAdminClient_create_com_google_cloud_pubsub_v1_TopicAdminSettings_). `TopicAdminSetting` has a `publishSetting` Method shown [here](https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/google-cloud-pubsub/latest/com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.stub.PublisherStubSettings#com_google_cloud_pubsub_v1_stub_PublisherStubSettings_publishSettings__)